# unable to import TA-Lib python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, ta-lib

I've a problem regarding the installation of [TA-Lib](https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/), I've followed both the documentation and this tutorial (https://blog.quantinsti.com/install-ta-lib-python/) but both don't seem to work. The [module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XMSC.png) is present but when I try to check in [vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWfkv.png) if the import works it just doesn't. But it does work on [anaconda prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToE7Q.png) so I don't know what the problem might be here.

Comment: What is the error code when you try to import it? Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: i've screened the error, it is in the vscode link. I can copy paste it here: >>> import talib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib'

Comment: about the virtual enviroment I honestly don't know, though I'm pretty sure I'm using Python: Select Interpreter -> Python 64-bit ('base': conda) which is the recommended one, how this info helps @TomMcLean !

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you may have common problem - you may have two Pythons installed - and module can be installed in one Python but you run code with other Python. Pythons don't shares modules. You can used in Python `print( sys.executable() )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and later use it to install modules `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the bottom-left of the VSCode, you can get which python interpreter you have selected.

[image]

From the picture you have provided, you have installed the `talib` package in the `conda:base` environment. So you should select the `conda:base` environment as the python interpreter.

Comment: I did but it doesn't work for some reason.. here the screenshot https://imgur.com/eCMjREO

Comment: @Pogus You have not activated the environment in the terminal. After you activated it, it will start with `(base)`

Comment: @Pogus Can you create a new environment with the shortcut of ctrl+shift+` ?

Comment: ctrl+shift+` doesn't work.. but I've tried to install TA LIB in a virtual enviroment using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wuuiga0wKdQ and it didn't fix much @Steven-MSFT !

Answer (score 0):

can you create a virtual environment and install TA LIB inside the virtual environment and open the folder in vs code and run it. I think that should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).